# POST with Fetch API to localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, json

[image: Your name here]

[JavaScript Vanilla] With these divs (that's not a form) I'm obtaining player's name. Now I want to POST it on my localhost, which works with JSON-Server, and I wrote that:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/db', { //OR 'http://localhost:3000/db' -same result
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        //"Content-type": "application/json; raw"
    },
    body: "Name = " + document.getElementById("name").value
})
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
```

But after that I get this error.

[image: Error]

I already have a 'db.json' file created in which I have an object.

Comment: If you can access `/db` in your browser, you're issuing a GET request. When you use `fetch`, you're issuing a POST request. Is it possible you only have the route for GET defined in your app?